# NodeJS Min Version

Tags: javascript, node.js, version

How to find out which is the minimum version of node that works in my project?

I'm making a project, but I don't know how I can find the minimum version of NodeJS to run the code, if anyone can help me I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try switching different versions of node with CLI with NVM (Node Version Manager).

Hope it helps!

Refer This: [https://blog.logrocket.com/how-switch-node-js-versions-nvm/#:~:text=Switching%20among%20Node.&text=7%3B%20we%20can%20simply%20run,or%20nvm%20use%2012%20command.](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-switch-node-js-versions-nvm/#:%7E:text=Switching%20among%20Node.&text=7%3B%20we%20can%20simply%20run,or%20nvm%20use%2012%20command.)